# NodeJS environment variables undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nodejs-server

I'm trying to create some envrioment variables but when I create the file and run the server the seem to be undefined. I'm using `nodemon`. I have restarted my server and no luck.

**UPDATED**

**.env**

```
MONGO_ATLAS_PW = "xxxx";
JWT_KEY = "secret_this_should_be_longer";
```

**package.json**

```
...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "start:server": "nodemon ./server/server.js"
  }
```

**app.js**

```
 require('dotenv').config();
 ...
 console.log(process.env.JWT_KEY); //undefined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This needed to be in the root directory of my project.

**nodemon.json**

```
{
  "env": {
    "MONGO_ATLAS_PW": "xxxx",
    "JWT_KEY": "secret_this_should_be_longer"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

I believe the nodemon.json file is only for setting nodemon specific configuration. If you look at the [nodemon docs for a sample nodemon.json file](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/sample-nodemon.md), the only env variable they mention setting is NODE_ENV.

Have you considered putting these environment variables for your app in a .env file instead? There is a package called [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) that is helpful for managing env variables in Node.

First, install dotenv using the command `npm install dotenv`

Then, create a file called `.env` in the root directory with the following:

```
MONGO_ATLAS_PW=xxxxx
JWT_KEY=secret_this_should_be_longer
```

Finally, inside your `app.js` file after your imports add the following line:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? Where is .env located in your project and where is app.js? .env should be in the root directory. Also, you haven't exactly copied the syntax for the .env file -- it should not be JavaScript syntax (though this wouldn't cause the variable to be undefined).

Answer (score 12):

I believe you're referring to the [dotenv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). To configure it, first create a file called `.env` with your keys and values stored like so:

```
MONGO_ATLAS_PW=xxxxx
JWT_KEY=secret_this_should_be_longer
```

Then, in your `server.js`, add this near the top:

```
require("dotenv").config();
```

Then the `process.env` variable will be an object containing the values in `.env`.

Comment: See the syntax - it needs to be that *exactly*. Try copy/pasting the `.env` in my answer into your file and see if that works @PatricioVargas.

Answer (score 2):

The env variable **do not contain the trailing white spaces** and also remove the quotes

```
MONGO_ATLAS_PW = "xxxx"; 
JWT_KEY = "secret_this_should_be_longer";
```

to

```
MONGO_ATLAS_PW=xxxx 
JWT_KEY=secret_this_should_be_longer
```

and **restart the server**

or you can also try using the nodemon.json - create a new file called **nodemon.json** in your **root directory**

```
{
    "env": {
        "MONGO_ATLAS_PW" : "xxxx",
        "JWT_KEY" : "secret_this_should_be_longer"
    }
}
```

and **restart the server**

for accessing the variable

```
process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW 
process.env.JWT_KEY
```

Answer (score 1):

This file nodemon.json needs to be in the root directory of your project.

**nodemon.json**

```
{
  "env": {
    "MONGO_ATLAS_PW": "xxxx",
    "JWT_KEY": "secret_this_should_be_longer"
  }
}
```

Install dotenv version 10.0.0 in the file below;
**nodemon.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "10.0.0",
  },
```

---

**index.js** (assuming its your main server)

Finally import into your main server file (index.js) as below;

```
require("dotenv").config();
```